# C# communication between forms bug

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm working on a GUI for an admin interface for management of a student complex. Currently the GUI has a listbox with predefined 6 rules for the students. In the beginning of the code, I add them to a list

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string rule in lbRules.Items)
                ruleList.Add(rule);
        }
```

Then, the GUI provides the admin with an option to modify the rules. To do so he selects a rule from the listbox and clicks a "Modify" button, which opens another form:

```
private void BtnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbRules.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                selectedRule = lbRules.SelectedItem.ToString();
                selectedIndex = lbRules.SelectedIndex;
                selectedRuleNumber = selectedRule.Substring(0, 3);
                selectedRule = selectedRule.Substring(6);
                var rulesForm = new Rules();
                rulesForm.Show();
            }

        }
```

On the second form load event I get the rule's text and number:

```
 private void Rules_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbRule.Text = Form1.selectedRuleNumber;
            tbModifyRule.Text = Form1.selectedRule;
        }
```

The text gets added to a RichTextBox, from where the rule can be edited.
Then the admin clicks a "Save" button, which gets the edited text from the RichTextBox(tbModifyRule) and adds it to a static ruleList in form1, sets a static boolean from form1 to true. Afterwards the second form gets closed:

```
 private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveRule = Form1.selectedRuleNumber + " - " + tbModifyRule.Text;
            Form1.ruleList.Insert(Form1.selectedIndex, saveRule);
            Form1.ruleList.RemoveAt(Form1.selectedIndex+1);
            Form1.formOpen = true;
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

At this point we are back to form1, in which we have a timer with timer_tick event. In there we check whether the boolean formOpen is true (which it is set before closing form2). Inside the if statement we clear the listbox and add each rule from the ruleList (previously edited in form2) to the listbox, then sets the formOpen back to false so it doesn't get executed all the time:

```
if (formOpen)
{
    lbRules.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string item in ruleList)
        lbRules.Items.Add(item);
}
formOpen = false;
```

Now this is really weird, and at this point makes absolutely no sense to me, since I tried debugging it for over an hour, trying different ways, which also led me to mysterious wonders of *WHY TF IT WORKS WHENEVER IT WANTS...*
So this works randomly, like it would work the first time, the second and third times it won't. Or vice versa. It's all random.
Strangely, I tried adding a breakpoint on the

```
lbRules.Items.Add(item);
```

in the foreach loop, so it stops on each item. And I actually saw the changed rule getting added from the ruleList into the listBox, however in the end it was not there.
And weirdly enough, I also tried adding the text from form2 in the listBox in form1, without using a list, but for whatever odd reason, I use the int selectedIndex, which gets the index of the selected item from the BtnModify_Click event to insert the text in that particular index, but this very index gets RANDOMLY set to bloody 0 after form2 closes.
hence, it again works from time to time, because at some tries it doesn't get set to 0 and it works.

```
if (formOpen)
            {
                selectedRule = Rules.saveRule;
                lbRules.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, selectedRule);
                lbRules.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex+1);
            }
            formOpen = false;
```

I don't assign value to this integer ANYWHERE else in the code.
I really tried digging some sense, but I hit a solid hard rock.
Any help appreciated!
And thanks for the time!

edit1:
as requested - rest of the timer method

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string text in ws.messages)
                message = text;

            if (ws.messages.Count > 0)
            {
                if (message.Contains("comp"))
                {

                    Complaints();
                    message = String.Empty;
                    ws.messages.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (formOpen)
            {   
                lbRules.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string item in ruleList)
                    lbRules.Items.Add(item);
            }
            formOpen = false;

        }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the reference for `Form1` that you're using in your `Rules` form?

Comment: Can you add the full code of the timer method.

Comment: @Enigmativity The ruleList, selectedRule, selectedRuleNumber are all static, so I refer to them using the Form1 class name.

Comment: @ShakHam The rest of the code in the timer method is not related
But I'll add it.

Comment: Just a suggestion on debugging, whenever you are using visual studio for debugging and multiple threads are running (like here Timer and UI thread) you won't be able to identify who overwrites the data. Simple logging could be writing in file with time and details you want to observe. Example : File.AppendAllText("sample.log",Time.TickElapsed+randomobject);

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd do a couple things:

1. Use a separate class for data exchange between forms, avoid using public static (I assume) form members for this.
2. Instead of a timer, subscribe to the `Form.Closed` event of `RulesForm`

This might make code flow a bit more predictable and allow you to find errors more easily.

Better yet, use the following pattern:

```
class Form1
{
   private void BtnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var ruleData = ..... //get current rule data
      var rulesForm = new Rules();
      rulesForm.SetData(ruleData); //pass initial state to the form
      rulesForm.SaveChanges = this.ApplyRules; //pass a method which will be called on save
      rulesForm.Show();
   }

   private bool ApplyRules(RuleData ruleData)
   {
       //do whatever you like with the rules here
       return true;
   }
}
```

```
class RuleForm
{
   public void SetData(RuleData ruleData)
   {
      //initialize fields, etc
   }

   public Func<RuleData, bool> SaveChanges { get; set; }

   private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var ruleData = .... //get data from form fields
       if(this.SaveChanges(ruleData))
           this.Close();
   }
}
```

```
class RuleData
{
 //whatever data you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to the following:

```
if (formOpen)
{   
  formOpen = false;
  lbRules.Items.Clear();
  foreach (string item in ruleList)
      lbRules.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The issue with having the `formOpen = false;` outside the `if` statement is that there is a chance that once the user clicks the Save button the timer could be about to execute the formOpen = false instruction setting it to false making the code inside the If statement to never be executed.

I truly believe this is not random but just a timing issue due to complicated logic.